# Where do I specify the database name in the getTables() method.

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, mssql-jdbc

The getTables() method is not returning any results for a table that exists in the database. I think the trouble is that is doesn't know which database to look at on the ip. How do I specify which database the getTables() method is supposed to be looking in as I have multiple databases with the same tables?

```
         //concatinating strings for IP to hit
        String ArchiveDB_URL = "jdbc:sqlserver://" + getArchiveIPaddress();


        //  Database credentials
        String USER = "Removed";
        String PASS = "Removed";

        Connection archiveConn = null;
        Statement archiveStmt = null;

        try {

            // Register JDBC driver
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

            // Open a connection   

            archiveConn = DriverManager.getConnection(ArchiveDB_URL, USER, PASS);

            DatabaseMetaData dbm = archiveConn.getMetaData();
            ResultSet rsTBmd = dbm.getTables(null,null, "[myDatabase].[dbo].[myTable]", new String[] {"TABLE"});

            System.out.println(rsTBmd.getString("TABLE_NAME"));

             if (rsTBmd.next()){
               //result sets start at 1 not 0
               int rsTBmdi = 1;  
               while(rsTBmd.next()){
                   System.out.println(rsTBmd.getString(rsTBmdi));
                   rsTBmdi++;
               }
           }
```

Comment: You could try using `archiveConn.setCatalog("myDatabase");` to set the current database.

Comment: Could you be a little more clear about the problem? Is it returning all of the tables from that database and missing one, or is it returning no tables at all, or is it returning the wrong tables entirely? Each of these could imply different problems (wrong server, lack of permissions, default database).

Comment: To: Gord Thompson   I put 'archiveConn.setCatalog("myDatabase");'  above  'DatabaseMetaData dbm = archiveConn.getMetaData();' it shows the following exception now "Database '[myDatabase]' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly." I know it exists, I can see the other tables that are being copied over.

Comment: To: Aaron Bertrand   This is supposed to be my attempt at checking if the table exists before I copy it to a different IP. When the table is there I can copy it fine, but for some reason I can't seem to get 'if (rsTBmd.next())' to return true.  When I put 'null' in the third argument of 'getTables()' I get the following printed out by the while loop. master
dbo
spt_fallback_usg
TABLE
null

Comment: Tip: When replying to comments, use @GordThompson, not "To: ...".

Comment: Turns out that `setCatalog` is not necessary; we can pass the catalog (database) name directly to `getTables`. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50103109/2144390).

Comment: You don't need to call `Class.forName`. The JDBC driver registers itself. That statement is superfluous.

Comment: You can't call `rsTBmd.getString("TABLE_NAME")` before calling `rsTBmd.next()` (and if it works, that is a bug in the driver implementation).

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel So that's why that wasn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first two arguments of [getTables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getTables(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) are `catalog` and `schemaPattern`. "Catalog" is another name for "Database", so just supply the database name as the first argument:

```java
ResultSet rsTBmd = dbm.getTables("myDatabase", "dbo", "myTable", new String[] {"TABLE"});
```

Note that in this case you do *not* enclose the names in square brackets, even if they contain spaces or "funny characters".

Comment: This method worked after I removed the additional brackets I had around my database name. I had added them because there are underscores and hyphens in most of the names. Evidently this method does not like brackets. Went from `[my_Database-v1]` to `my_Database-v1`

Comment: @NullPointerProliferator The JDBC API specifies that you should specify the object name as it's stored in the metadata tables of the target database. SQL Server does not include the brackets in its metadata tables.

Comment: @Mark Rottevell I'd had to put the brackets so the insert, select, and delete statements could handle the underscores and hyphens in the database names. I'd been using them so much in my StringBuilder variable I forgot they were there.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connection-url-sample?view=sql-server-2017), your JDBC URL looks like `"jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=AdventureWorks;user=UserName;password=*****";`, making your code:

```
    //  Database credentials
    String USER = "Removed";
    String PASS = "Removed";

    Connection archiveConn = null;
    Statement archiveStmt = null;

    try {

        // Register JDBC driver
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

        // Open a connection   
     //concatinating strings for IP to hit
    String ArchiveDB_URL = "jdbc:sqlserver://" + getArchiveIPaddress() + ";database=myDatabase;username="+USER+";password="+PASS;

        archiveConn = DriverManager.getConnection(ArchiveDB_URL);

        DatabaseMetaData dbm = archiveConn.getMetaData();
        ResultSet rsTBmd = dbm.getTables(null,null, "[myDatabase].[dbo].[myTable]", new String[] {"TABLE"});

        System.out.println(rsTBmd.getString("TABLE_NAME"));

         if (rsTBmd.next()){
           //result sets start at 1 not 0
           int rsTBmdi = 1;  
           while(rsTBmd.next()){
               System.out.println(rsTBmd.getString(rsTBmdi));
               rsTBmdi++;
           }
       }
```

I do hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the database name in the *ArchiveDB_URL*

```
String ArchiveDB_URL = "jdbc:sqlserver://" + getArchiveIPaddress() + "/yourDatabaseNameHere";
```